# Testing Laravel 5.2.x custom package using Laravel API

Tags: api, testing, package, laravel-5

As Laravel documentation says, Laravel provides a very fluent API for making HTTP requests to your application, examining the output, and even filling out forms. See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/testing#application-testing

So, how could I test a custom Laravel package using Laravel API **without a previous Laravel installation**?

Por example, in a Laravel project, you can test HTTP requests using Laravel API like this:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5')
             ->dontSee('Rails');
    }
}
```

As I read, many people use [Laravel Package Unit Testing Helper](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) to tests their packages but then you can't use Laravel methods like `$this->visit('/')` to make your test, or is this possible?

If it isn't possible with this package, how could I make Laravel API use testing in my package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can still extend TestCase in your package tests. Say your package is in the location `vendor/your_name/package_name`. You can easily run `vendor/bin/phpunit vendor/your_name/package_name` and the tests in that package will be run.

Comment: But you need a previous Laravel installation. Is there any way to do it without a previous Laravel installation?

Comment: What do you mean by a previous Laravel installation? You mean previous version? I don't get why you would.

Comment: That firstly you need install Laravel with composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel new_project. Secondly, install your package with composer install package_name. And thirdly run what you are saying: vendor/bin/phpunit vendor/your_name/package_name. 
It is not like this?